# Angular how to change the validity of formcontrol or formgroup depending whether the checkbox is checked or not using reactive forms

Tags: angular5

how to change the required validity of formcontrol or formgroup depending whether the checkbox is checked or not using reactive forms.

```
     createForm() {
    this.dvraForm = this.fb.group({ // <-- the parent FormGroup
        primary: this.fb.group({
            txtpremiumDVRA: ['', [Validators.required, ValidatePremium]],
            txtSumInsured: '',
        }),
        fund: this.fb.group({
            txtMoneyMarketFund: '100',
            txtFixedIncomeFund: '0',
        }, {
            validator: totalFund('txtMoneyMarketFund', 'txtFixedIncomeFund'),
            validator2: totalFund2('txtMoneyMarketFund', 'txtFixedIncomeFund')}),
        cbTopUp: false,
        topUp: this.fb.group({
            cboTopUpFrequency: '',
            txtStartPolicyYear: ['', Validators.required,],
            txtNoofTopUpYrs: ['', Validators.required,],
            txtTopUpAmount: ['', [Validators.required, ValidateTopUpAmountDVRA]]
        }),
    });

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can programatically add or remove validators to any formControls.
You can subscribe to valuChanges Observable of the checkbox (if it is not a control you can handle it in click event).
You can remove validators based on the events coming to ValueChanges of the checkbox like so.
Clearing validators

```
this.form.controls.requiredControl.clearValidators();
this.form.updateValueAndValidity(); // this is to rerun form validation after removing the validation for a field.
```

Setting validators

```
this.form.controls.requiredControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
this.form.updateValueAndValidity(); // this is to rerun form validation after removing the validation for a field.
```

Comment: how do i do that can you send me some sample using plunker? i am new in angular